# Java Vaadin Web Application not Deploying on Glassfish Server

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, vaadin

I was working on a Vaadin Web Project on Netbeans IDE, until it stopped deploying on Glassfish server. I don't know what the reason is, and I have tried searching everywhere..

The Project is building successfully; however, it is not deploying on the glassfish server as it did before. I would appreciate it if someone is able to find a solution or help me undertstand what's wrong with my Vaadin WebApp now.

Below is the Netbeans Output when Running my Project:

```
Deploying on GlassFish Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/CarRentalsClient-1.0
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
cd /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" -Dnetbeans.deploy=true package
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building CarRentalsClient 1.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.7:update-theme (default) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Updating theme VAADIN/themes/mytheme
Widgetsets found from classpath:
Addon styles found from classpath:

Search took 12ms
Theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" updated

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.7:update-widgetset (default) @ CarRentalsClient ---
GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
No widgetsets found - generating AppWidgetset if necessary.
Updating widgetset AppWidgetset
Adding resource directory to command classpath: /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/src/main/resources
Adding resource directory to command classpath: /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/generated-resources/gwt
Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.1.7
Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.1.7
Widgetsets found from classpath:
    com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:/Users/*****/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/8.1.7/vaadin-client-8.1.7.jar!/
Addon styles found from classpath:

Search took 16ms

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.7:compile-theme (default) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Updating theme VAADIN/themes/mytheme
Theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" compiled

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ CarRentalsClient ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.7:compile (default) @ CarRentalsClient ---
GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.1.7
Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.1.7

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ CarRentalsClient ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/src/test/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Surefire report directory: /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


--- maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) @ CarRentalsClient ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [CarRentalsClient] in [/Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/CarRentalsClient-1.0]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [/Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/src/main/webapp]
Processing overlay [ id eu.cz.cvut.fit.abdulab1:CarRentalsClient]
Processing overlay [ id eu.cz.cvut.fit.abdulab1:CarRentals]
Webapp assembled in [1874 msecs]
Building war: /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/CarRentalsClient-1.0.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 14.089s
Finished at: Thu Dec 21 08:16:24 CET 2017
Final Memory: 19M/442M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Deploying on GlassFish Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at /Users/*****/NetBeansProjects/CarRentalsClient/target/CarRentalsClient-1.0
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
```